# How do I set a global function in Postman?

Tags: function, methods, global, postman, newman

I'd like to declare a function once in the pre-request script of my first postman request and then use it in every request thereafter. I've set plenty of variables on the postman object and as environment variables but I haven't found a way to do the same with functions.

In the pre-request script:

```
function wrapTest(param1, param2, param3) {
...
}
```

Then I've tried

1. ```
   postman.prototype.wrap = wrapTest;
   ```
2. ```
   postman.wrap = wrapTest;
   ```
3. ```
   postman.setGlobalVariable("wrap", wrapTest);
   ```

In the request I'm attempting to use this function:

```
postman.wrap(one,two,three);
```

which results in "postman.wrap is not a function" in all cases.

Comment: Here's my answer in another thread and I hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60192186/2502263

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function can be saved as a string and then evaled when it's used.

```
var stringWrap = function wrapTest(param1, param2, param3) {
...
};

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("wrap", stringWrap);
var parsedFunc = eval("("+environment.wrap+")");
parsedFunc("1", 2, 3);
```

Comment: `stringWrap` should be a multi line string: ```var stringWrap = `function wrapTest(param1, param2, param3) {
...
};`
```