# Why can't I add a simple reusable function to Postman?

Tags: javascript, postman

In Postman, I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. In a collection:

   1. Create a utility object containing reusable functions
   2. Store that utility object in a global variable for later use in request test scripts.
2. In a request:

   1. Pull the utility object code out of the global variables.
   2. Eval the code and store the resulting utility object instance in a local variable.
   3. Invoke a method on the utility object instance.

None of the many implementations I've seen scattered across the web seem to work, though. I can get all the way down to step 2.2, and then things just die a horrible flaming death. The JavaScript engine beneath Postman refuses to evaluate the object stored in the globals collection.

To isolate the issue, I've stripped this down to a bare minimum script, which is placed in the pre-request scripts for my collection:

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("loadUtils", function utils() {
    let utils = {};
    utils.main = function() {
        console.log("Hello, world!");
    }
    return utils;
} + ';utils()');
```

I then try to load this script as follows:

```
var code = globals.loadUtils;
console.log(code);
var utils = eval('(' + code + ')');
```

But the following error always occurs:

> There was an error in evaluating the test script:  SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token ;

I tried:

- Converting the entire function to a multi-line string and storing that result in the globals environment. The same error occurred.
- Including the enclosing parentheses directly in the function body. That didn't work, either.
- Using lambda expressions, but that caused all sorts of problems in the editor itself.

I'm certain that this is something simple, stupid, and obvious, and that I am just not seeing it.

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

P.S. This should be possible, as suggested [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673961/how-to-write-global-functions-in-postman) and the [Postman forums on GitHub](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4058) (though it requires some scrolling through the comments to see the solution).

Comment: What happens if you change `;utils()` to `()` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms Same response.I gutted the body so that it contains `let utils = {}; return utils;` and still got the `Unexpected token ;` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You store two statements as a string, which are seperated by a semicolon:

```
 "function utils() { /*...*/ }; utils()"
```

then you wrap that string in parentheses and try to execute it:

```
eval("(function { /*...*/ }; utils())")
```

that won't work, as a `;` inside of an expression is a syntax error.

You either remove the parens, replace the semicolon with a colon or use an IIFE (which I'd favor here):

```
eval("(" + someFunc + ")()");
```

Comment: That's really odd. That's the techinique used on the most upvoted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673961/how-to-write-global-functions-in-postman), which is almost the same problem I'm having.

Comment: @mike no it isn't. `eval(globals.loadUtils)` <- no parens

Comment: I'm referring to the two semicolons -- it's in the top code block, where he has `} + '; loadUtils();');`. But it's neither here nor there. In the end, Do you think I need to add an additional set of parentheses?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `eval`, add something like the following to your **Collection's** pre request script.

```
/* You can add collection level functions to this utils object that will be available throughout 
 the collection's requests' pre-request scripts and tests. */
utils = {
    /** This is an example function
     * @param pm pass the current pm so that this has the correct context
    */
    reusableFunction: function(pm) {
        console.log("do something amazing here instead of just logging, including manipulating environment or request, access the response, etc. That is why you pass in the pm. Request: " + JSON.stringify(pm.request));
    }
}
```

This function is usable in any of the collection request's pre-request script or tests.
[image]