# How to use data in csv file row wise to be used per request via newman?

Tags: api, collections, postman, newman, data-files

I have bunch of requests in my postman collection for example :- 
Request 1 
Request 2
...
Request N

For each of these requests , I want to pass a client id for which is unique per request. I have created a data file with those client ids. So the data in CSV file is as follows : -
Client Id 
1
2
..
N

My requirement is to use Client ID 1 in Request 1 , Client ID 2 in Request 2 instead of iterating Client ID 1 though the entire collection.

So basically data in CSV file to be used row wise in all the requests.

Would really appreciate suggestions on how this can be achieved.

I tried using Runner but it doesn't fit my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would be easier not to use .csv file here, but *Postman Environment Variables*.

If you're having the number of *ClientIDs* matches the number of request, you can do something like this:

In the *Pre-Request Script* of first request you have to initiate an array of *clientIDs*:

```
const clientIdArr =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
pm.environment.set('clientIdArr', clientIdArr);
```

Then we will shift the first value of array of clientID in every subsequent *Postman Collection* request:

```
const currentArr = pm.environment.get('clientIdArr');
const currentValue = currentArr.shift();
pm.environment.set('clientIdArr', currentArr);
pm.environment.set('currentClientId', currentValue);
```

Then you can use `{{currentClientId}}` environment variable in your actual request and exectute the *Postman Collection* via *Collection Runner.*

For more details how `Array.prototype.shift()` works please refer to the following [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

If you have a large amount of requests in your *Postman Collection* you might consider having those scripts as [Postman Global Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673961/how-to-write-global-functions-in-postman).

Comment: Thank you @n-verbitsky for your time and response. I will give this a try.