# Postman| Is there a way to set a function globally to work in all Collections?

Tags: postman

I am trying to set a function to work in all of my collections in Postman.

Each of my collections has different environment, and I want to set the function only once to use it on all of my collections so I won't have to copy the function to each one of them.

I have found solutions that makes functions as global through requests in the same collections, but not over all of the collections.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Write Global Functions in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673961/how-to-write-global-functions-in-postman)

Comment: @vgro No, I want a function to work in all collections, in your link they made a function to work in all requets in one collection