# Run pre-request script on each API request in postman

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script

Can this randomString(length) be reused in another pre-request script instead of having in each API request in postman?

```
function randomString(length){
  var char ='';
  while(chars.length < length ){
    chars += Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
  }
  returns chars.substring(0,length);
};
```

Comment: is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54128571/11960598) helps?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can store the function in an environment variable and then use the eval() function.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the pre-script for the collections, it will then run before every request.